# Node.js - find by array of IDs, including repeated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to find customers who purchased tickets, including customers who purchased the same ticket more than once. e.g

```
const customerIDs = [
  ObjectID('5ac5df7f73db2a3e48c516dd'),
  ObjectID('5ac5df7f73db2a3e48c516dd'), // Same thing
];

Customer.find({_id: customerIDs}).then(
  customers => {
    console.log(customers);      
  }
);
```

But when I run this, only one customer is returned i.e unique data. But I want the same number of customers as the amount of items in `customerIDs` to be returned (unique or not)

Answer (score 0):

The objectId in mongodb is always unique, and the customer table will have only one result for your case.

Comment: Okay I get that. But is there anyway to still get the repeated data